# Vuex Error ypeError: Object(...) is not a function

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuejs3

I am getting a blank white screen when running "npm run serve" .In the browser console it says that
[image: Error]

I am using ,Vue3 , Vuetifiy , Vuex4 and vue-router.

Here is my index.js file for vuex

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
  },
  mutations: {
  },
  actions: {
  },
  modules: {
  }
})
And my github repo link : https://github.com/mertpinarbasi/vue-to-do
```

Comment: `import Vue from 'vue'` - this is not how Vue 3 is used

Comment: How can i fix this problem

Comment: Check the documentation how Vue 3 is used, https://v3.vuejs.org/api/application-api.html#use . You'd get a working example by initializing Vue CLI project.

Comment: I am appreciate for you help , by the way I am a fan of the From Software games too :)